# Windows Driver signing: Do I need EV or simple certification

Tags: windows, driver, signing, wdk, driver-signing

I am reading Microsoft documentation on how to sign a driver for windows 10 X64 and I am getting different information from the Microsoft website.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/release-signing?source=recommendations) explains how to sign a driver by the developer without the need to send it to Microsoft.

[This document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-hardware-certification/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10-version-1607/ba-p/364894) explains how to submit the driver to Microsoft for signing.

and on other sites, the information is very different.

I need to sign my driver which I will send alongside my hardware to the user (so no need to be part of the windows update).

How can I sign it? which procedures should I follow and which certificate should I buy?

Comment: First document is out of date. If you want to ship drivers for modern Windows you need Microsoft to sign it on the Dev Portal, and that requires an EV certificate.

Comment: What kind of driver are you signing?  Does it actually contain a `.sys` files with code you are loading into the kernel?  If so, who wrote that code and was it maybe already signed by the developers?

Comment: @Luke Can you please elaborate? is there any step-by-step tutorial on how to sign a driver?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: yes, it is a kernel driver and has *.sys files. I am writing the code based on a code that I have received from a company as a sample deriver for their system.  As I am modifying their code, I need to sign it.

Comment: The instructions are pretty straightforward: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/code-signing-attestation

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing actual kernel-mode code, you need an EV certificate, which you will use to submit drivers to the "Windows Hardware Developer Center Dashboard portal".  See the announcement here:

[Driver signing changes in Windows 10](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-hardware-certification/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10/ba-p/364859)

Just in case this requirement changes in the future, I recommend signing up for the portal first and looking through its user interface and/or documentation to figure out what the current requirements are before your invest in a certificate.

After you submit your driver to Microsoft, they will apply a signature to it that will allow it to be distributed to the end users; you shouldn't have to worry about the details of that signature.

Comment: Is this the same as "Attestation sign Windows 10+ drivers" suggested by @Luke

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Attestation signing is one method of signing; it's lightweight and far simpler than running the HLK/HCK tests. Either way, you have to submit the drivers through the Partner Center which requires an EV certificate.